# -> Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found

Tags: sdk, android-14

```
\*\*\* my build.gradle(android)

  buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 34
    targetSdkVersion = 34

dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2")
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.6.1'}

****i'm shifting my project sdk 34 from 33 and facing issue regarding devsupportmanager and i'm    not able to find the exact place where the error is causing so please help me find this ?? here im   using gradle version 7.2.2 and gradle wrapper version is
```

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask